# Display username - Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using BehaviorSubject to display the username in the header component after logging in, and everything works fine. However, when I reload the page, the username no longer appears. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? 
*header.component.ts*

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{
  isLogin:boolean = false;
  username:string = '';
  searchValue = '';
  form:FormGroup;
  constructor(private authService:AuthenticationService,
              private router:Router){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLogged();
    this.getUsername();
  }

  isLogged(){
    this.authService.currentIsLogged$.subscribe(isLoggin=> this.isLogin = isLoggin);
  }

  getUsername(){
    this.authService.currentUsername$.subscribe(username=> this.username = username);
  }
}
```

*header.component.html*

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
            <ng-container *ngIf="isLogin;else login">
              <span>Hello {{username}}</span>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #login>
              <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="user">
                <mat-icon
                  fontIcon="account_circle"></mat-icon>
              </button>
              <mat-menu #user="matMenu">
                <div class="p-3 custom-size">
                  <a class="user-part" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
                </div>
                <div class="px-3 pb-3">
                  <a class=user-part routerLink="/register">Register</a>
                </div>
              </mat-menu>
            </ng-template>
</div>
```

*authentication.service.ts*

```
export class AuthenticationService {
   isLogged = new BehaviorSubject(false);
   username = new BehaviorSubject('');

  currentIsLogged$ = this.isLogged.asObservable();
  currentUsername$ = this.username.asObservable();


  constructor(private http:HttpClient,
              private tokenService:TokenService) { }

  public authenticate(request:AuthenticationRequest){
    return this.http.post<AuthenticationResponse>(`${AUTH_API}/auth/authenticate`, request)
      .pipe(
        tap(token=>{
          this.tokenService.setAccessToken(token.accessToken);
          this.tokenService.setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken);
          this.isLogged.next(true);
          this.username.next(this.tokenService.getUsername());
        }),
        catchError((err)=>{
          console.log("Error handled by Service..." + err.status)
          return throwError(()=> new Error(err.error.message));
        })
      );
  }
}
```

*login.component.ts*

```
public login(authRequest:AuthenticationRequest){
    let resp = this.authService.authenticate(authRequest);
    resp.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.utilService.openSnackBar('Success', 'Close')
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.utilService.openSnackBar(error, 'Close')
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Note:** My accessToken (JWT) contains username and user roles

Comment: It looks like `username` gets set when the auth service `authenticate` method is called.  When you refresh, are you calling `authenticate()` somewhere?

Comment: @BizzyBob no the `authenticate()` only called when a user log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow is currently set your BehaviorSubject `username`, this gets referenced by an observable `currentUsername$`. Then your component takes the data and puts it into it's own variable `this.username = username`. That's a lot of extra steps just to display the data from your BehaviorSubject. Why not just directly reference the BehaviorSubject in your template?

```html
...
<span>Hello {{tokenService.username.value}}</span>
...
```

By doing it this way, you don't have to worry about all these extra variables, subscriptions, unsubscribing, etc. And you will always have the latest information even though there is no verbose subscription. If you just want to display information from a BehaviorSubject in a template, just use `.value` on it. Super easy and no mess to cleanup. You can also subscribe to it directly without using `asObservable()` if you want to do something in your component when the value changes.

Edit: I would also recommend converting isLogged and username into a single BehaviorSubject of a `User` (or better yet, a Signal if you are on the latest Angular!) so you have less to keep track of. If the user BehaviorSubject is null, you aren't logged in. If it isn't null, grab the username from it.

Comment: I put this `this.username = authService.user.value` in ngDoCheck hook and it still works. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: This is also fine to do, but ultimately you don't need or even really want to. There is a coding principle called "Single source of truth" which means you shouldn't have multiple places where a value lives but instead you should have one single place that the true value lives and everything else references that variable. So anywhere that you would reference `this.username`. why not just directly reference `authService.user.value`? You will have far fewer issues where you update a value in your service but your components don't pick up on the change because now your components don't need to.

Comment: Also put a console log after this.username in the ngDoCheck and see how many times that runs. You don't really want to do too much in the recycled Angular lifecycle hooks because you will more than likely run into spamming your code or potentially infinite loops. If run a check, then set a variable, which forces an update, so you do a check, which sets a variable, which forces an update....etc. Not all lifecycle hooks are prone to this but some are so I just recommend using them with caution. OnInit and AfterViewInit are the only ones I recommend for standard use.

Answer (score 1):

As @MylesMorrone said besides referencing to your `BehaviorSubject` directly in  `header.component.ts` like this:

```
isLogin$ = inject(AuthenticationService).isLogged;
```

you can also use `async` pipe in your template.

```
...
<span>Hello {{isLogin$ | async}}</span>
...
```

`Async` pipe will take care of subscribing, retrieving the data and unsubscribing when component is destroyed. So this:

```
this.authService.currentIsLogged$.subscribe(isLoggin=> this.isLogin = isLoggin);
```

won't be necessary anymore.
`Async` pipe will also react to changes of value.